# How to find consecutive hashtags

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string:

```
"hello #a and #b welcome #b #c #d and #e #f or #k"
```

I want the sequences of more than one consecutive hashtags. I want the output:

```
"#b #c #d", "#e #f"
```

I used the following regex:

```
/#\w+\s*(#\w+\s*)+(#\w+)*/
```

but it does not work.

Comment: This might be what you want: `(#\w+\s+(#\w+\s+)+)` http://rubular.com/r/ZgQPwpUa2d

Comment: `"#b #c #d", "#e #f"` is not a valid Ruby object. You cannot get such output.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the last capturing group and make the second last a non capturing group. But then you will also match the trailing whitespace.

If you don't want the trailing whitespace you could use:
`#\w+(?:\s+#\w+)+`

[Regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/Kh4OaE0VCI)

If you also want to match hashtags without zero or more times a whitespace character, you could use [`\s*`](http://rubular.com/r/nyKHRSX5Yj) instead of `\s+`

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
((#\w+\s+){2,})
```

group 1 has the result.